# Add user to application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

How do you use curl to add a developer (or tester) to your application via their facebook id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add test users to your app using CURL. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

`https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
  installed=true
  &name=FULL_NAME
  &locale=en_US
  &permissions=read_stream
  &method=post
  &access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: Yes I know how to add test users. My question specifically says a developer or tester when I have their facebook id... meaning a real person who is already a facebook friend... not a fictitious user

Comment: You do it via the GUI, there is no programmatic way of creating a real user or linking an existing real user.  Just go to: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/permissions`

Comment: I feel like there is a better solution... I'm going to choose your answer though because you gave the curl command for adding test users which is also pretty helpful thanks!